# Are there any way to change the Membership Provider & Role Manager through code or Powershell

Tags: administration, authentication, forms-authentication, configuration, claims-based-auth

I know that you can specify the Membership provider and Role manager for a web application on creation, but I need to update it after creation. any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are stored in Web.Config file. Use following techniques to work with web.config files in SharePoint world.

[Working with Web.config Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460914.aspx)

[How to: Add and Remove Web.config Settings Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx)

It is important to update the config files the "sharepoint way" so that the changes can be applied to all Web Servers in the farm.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,, but what's the SharePoint way (Code or Powershell).

Comment: I don't think it's actually in Web.config,, if you try creating a new web application and set it's Membership provider while creating it (In Central Admin) you won't find this provider in web.config of the web app.

Comment: I meant using SpwebconfigModification object no matter code or powershell.

Comment: so If I didn't enter the Membership setting from the Central Admin and just set it in web.config it will work?

Comment: It works because ultimately what matters is the content of web.config and not the how it was entered. But I prefer to use as outlined in links above because it takes takes care of multiple servers in the farm.

Answer (score 3):

You will find entries similar to the following in the  section of the web.config for your web application or in the root web.config if you configured FBA at the IIS root.  You can change the name(s) directly in the web.config file.

```
    <roleManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="FBARoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="FBAMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" passwordFormat="Clear" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <add name="FBAProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="FBA" />
        </providers>
    </profile>
```

If you don't see these entries in the web.config for your web app, look in the web.config file found in your .NET CONFIG folder (i.e. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you can also set the membership and role provider when you extend an application.

You could just delete the IIS site from the application management, and then create the default zone again, specifying the membership and role providers.

You still need to modify the web.config, though. There's no escaping that.